# Difference between normal function and the shorter function syntax added in ES6?

Tags: javascript, function, super

So, ES6 has added this way of defining a function,

```
func() { }
```

And then we have the old way of doing the same,

```
function func() {}
```

As far as, I understand

1. We can use the new short syntax in object and classes only.
2. And ES6 classes can only have these short syntax functions, adding long function syntax gives error

I am trying to understand what is the actual implementation difference between the two. Is it related to the use of `this` or `super` key word.

Comment: Not quite "a new way of defining a function". That's a way to define a **method**, which is necessarily bound to a class as you have pointed out.

Comment: But we can define it in an object as well.

Comment: Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha an object is merely an instance of a class.

Comment: @YangshunTay You are saying that the new and old syntax can be called method and function respectively. right ?

Comment: "*What is the actual difference between the two?*" - uh, the one makes the function a part of a (class prototype) object, the other declares a variable in the local scope?

Comment: @Bergi ok so, short syntax defines the class prototype. But in case I use both syntaxes on an object it shows no difference. e.g. ----- `obj={f: function(){}, d(){}}`

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

Here are some of the ways you can declare a function (that can possibly be named `doSomething`):

**Normal function declaration (for the lack of a better world)**

This can defined in any block in your code

```
function doSomething() {
}
```

**Class method and Object shorthand syntax (ES6 only)**

These can only be declared inside Class blocks and objects where the `function` keyword isn't required

```
class MyClass {
  doSomething() { // class method
  }
}

// ES6
const myObject = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 'baz',
  doSomething() { // shorthand: key 'doSomething' whose value is a function
  },
}

// ES5 (also ES6)
var myObject = {
  foo: 1,
  doSomething: function doSomething() {
  },
}
```

**Anonymous Functions (functions without a name)**

```
// doesn't have a name but can be invoked using the variable name
const myFunction = function () {}
```

**Callback functions (also can be anonymous)**

```
fetch('/path/to/page').then(function () {
  // do something
})

// same as above but with name
fetch('/path/to/page').then(function doSomething() {
  // do something
})
```

**Immediately-Invoked Functions (IIFE)**

```
(function doSomething() {
  // do something immediately
}())
```

I'm going to pause here to note that all of the above types of function declaration above have their own scope. Meaning, the `this` keyword references the actual function, not its surrounding scope.

**Arrow functions (lexically scoped)**

Meaning that these functions keeps surrounding context when using the `this` keyword.

```
const doSomething = () => {
  // do something
}

const myObject = {
  doSomething: () => {
    // do something
  }
}

fetch('/path/to/page').then(() => {
  // do something
})

(() => {
  // do something immediately
})()
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It lists a bunch of syntax related to functions, but it doesn't explain the difference that was asked about.

Comment: I tried to answer the question in the first two options by explaining the difference between ES6 and ES5 and what the syntax means.